# Foreman-Installer change certificate

Tags: rhel6, puppetmaster, foreman

Looking to install Foreman for a puppet deployment in my environment.  I ran foreman-installer with defaults at first and didn't care for the SSL certificates and URLs being server01.example.com

I would prefer it to use a cname like puppet.example.com which is more descriptive and a default puppet agent setting. It should make foreman/puppet migrations in the future easier, being able to copy the certificates directory and changing the cname record.

I know I can change all the settings interactively using foreman-install -i but changing records in that fashion makes for poor documentation.  I'm trying to find the right options to have this setup the way I intend but it's not working.

Here is the command and options I am using:

```
sudo foreman-installer --foreman-foreman-url=https://puppet.example.com:8443 \ 
--foreman-proxy-registered-name=puppet.example.com \ 
--puppet-server-foreman-ssl-key=/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.example.com.pem \ 
--foreman-proxy-ssl-cert=/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet.example.com.pem \ 
--foreman-proxy-foreman-base-url=https://puppet.example.com \ 
--foreman-proxy-ssl-cert=/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet.example.com.pem \ 
--foreman-proxy-ssl-key=/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.example.com.pem \ 
--puppet-server-foreman-url=https://puppet.example.com \ 
--foreman-proxy-registered-proxy-url=https://puppet.example.com:8443`
```

After running that command it tries to start the foreman-proxy service and fails.  It's looking for the private key named /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.example.com.pem but the key that is there is /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/server01.example.com.pem.  It is still using the FQDN for creating the certificates.

How can I get this setup the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience some installer settings can't be rewritten just by running foreman-installer again, the hostname for instance. You need to restore the installer file and when you run the installer again it will use the new data (hostname, fqdn,...)

Overwrite /etc/foreman/foreman-installer-answers.yaml with [the default file](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-foreman/blob/master/foreman-installer-answers.yaml) and run `foreman-installer` again, it will use the new hostname